# Does the following unitary matrix factorization have a name?

Tags: orthogonal-matrices

I know any unitary matrix can be factored as follows:
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{U}} }  = \left( {\prod\limits_{j = N}^1 {\underline {\overline {\bf{\Psi }} } \left( {{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_j}} \right)} } \right)\underline {\overline {\bf{\Phi }} }$$
Here, each
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{\Psi }} } \left( {{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_i}} \right) = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ {i - 1} \right]}} - \frac{{{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_i}\underline {\bf{w}} _i^ + }}{{1 + \sqrt {1 - \underline {\bf{w}} _i^ + {{\underline {\bf{w}} }_i}} }}}&{{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_i}}&{\underline {\overline {\bf{0}} } }\\
{ - \underline {\bf{w}} _i^ + }&{\sqrt {1 - \underline {\bf{w}} _i^ + {{\underline {\bf{w}} }_i}} }&{{{\underline {\bf{0}} }^ + }}\\
{\underline {\overline {\bf{0}} } }&{\underline {\bf{0}} }&{{{\underline {\overline {\bf{I}} } }_{\left[ {N - i} \right]}}}
\end{array}} \right]$$
is a primitive unitary matrix depending only upon the $i - 1{\rm{ }}x{\rm{ }}1$ complex vector
$${\underline {\bf{w}} _i} = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{w_{1i}}}\\\vdots \\{{w_{\left( {i - 1} \right)i}}}
\end{array}} \right]$$
with the only constraint on ${\underline {\bf{w}} _i}$ being that $\left| {{{\underline {\bf{w}} }_i}} \right| \le 1$; $\underline {\overline {\bf{\Phi }} }$  is an $N{\rm{ }}x{\rm{ }}N$ diagonal phase matrix, i.e.
$$\underline {\overline {\bf{\Phi }} }  = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{e^{j{\varphi _1}}}}& \cdots &0\\
 \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0& \cdots &{{e^{j{\varphi _N}}}}
\end{array}} \right]$$
See [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1JunjKxazANM0RtbzhGTi1ZSVU) for a proof of this assertion.

The real case is analogous, other than each ${\underline {\bf{w}} _i}$ is real rather than complex, and $\underline {\overline {\bf{\Phi }} }$ reduces to a sign matrix (i.e., all $\pm 1$ entries).

Does this factorization have a standard name?